# How to label to merge dataframe

Tags: r

From two data frames:

```
dframe1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text=c("text1","text2","text3"))
dframe2 <- data.frame(id = c(4,5,6), text=c("text1","text2","text3"))
```

How is it possible to merge them and label the id column:

```
dframe <- data.frame(id = c(e1,e2,e3,w4,w5,w6), 
        text=c("text1","text2","text3","text1","text2","text3"))
```

Comment: rbind, perhaps?

Comment: @jdobres and how can you label every row?

Comment: data.frames always have row labels, they are the `?row.names`. Maybe you want `factor(id, labels = c(e1,e2,e3,w4,w5,w6))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I want to label the id column of the first dataframe with a specific letter and the same for the second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
dframe1$id <- paste0("e", dframe1$id)
dframe2$id <- paste0("w", dframe2$id)

rbind(dframe1, dframe2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a couple `dplyr` and `tidyr` functions, you can do this in a way that 1) leaves the original data frames unchanged, 2) doesn't require checking how many rows are in each, as you might with a `rep`-based solution, and 3) scales to more than just 2 data frames, since `rbind` can only take 2 data frames in one call.

`bind_rows` has an argument `.id` that will create a column of IDs based on the names of your data frame, if you pass them as a named list. That list can be as many data frames as you need. Then `unite` merges two (or more) columns into one, to put those data frame names and row IDs together.

```r
dframe1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text=c("text1","text2","text3"))
dframe2 <- data.frame(id = c(4,5,6), text=c("text1","text2","text3"))

tidyr::unite(dplyr::bind_rows(list(e = dframe1, w = dframe2), .id = "df_id"),
             col = id, 
             df_id, id, sep = "")
#>   id  text
#> 1 e1 text1
#> 2 e2 text2
#> 3 e3 text3
#> 4 w4 text1
#> 5 w5 text2
#> 6 w6 text3
```

Or in more common `dplyr` piped syntax:

```r
library(dplyr)
list(e = dframe1, w = dframe2) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "df_id") %>%
  tidyr::unite(col = id, df_id, id, sep = "")
```